# Faster method than Point.distance to calculate collision between objects?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, collision-detection

I'm developing a game where I have lots of collisions, and it rapidly came to notice that my bottleneck is this line:

```
if(Point.distance(_point1, _point2) < collisionDistance){
  //do stuff
}
```

where _point1 and _point2 are static variables that store the positions of objects that could collide if the collisionDistance is low enough.

Do you know of any more performant method to check a simple collision between two circles?.

Comment: It's just a method call, it doesn't create any objects. If that method call is still too much make an inline equivalent or just plug the math formula directly.

Comment: I bet you have too many collision checks. While you can speed up `Point.distance` *a little bit* by using inline math, there's probably a better solution to avoid checking distance so much, such as [spatial partitioning](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2009/11/as3_proximityma.html).

Comment: Does it use a quadtree?.

Comment: No, that example uses a grid. [A quad-tree is another example](https://github.com/martinkallman/collision-as3/wiki/Quadtree-class). Anything other than checking every object against every other object will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in Point.distance function is really slow, so supply your own.

There are lots of optimizations to be had for distance between two 2D points (you're are using circles, so adjust the collision distance by the circle's radius) and a lot depends on how the different compilers optimize, but in this case we are only talking about the asc compiler.

The first basic way is the Euclidean (Pythagorean) distance that everyone learns in trig. class. Other methods such as Taxicab/Manhattan method works well for grid/tile based games. Using the fast inverse square root is wick fast, but hard (impossible?) to implement in straight ActionScript, but can be done in ABC bytecode (via ALCHEMY, apparat, As3c, etc..) (This is the way I went *once* for a really tough distance problem... but usually it is not worth the extra work).

Here is part of a benchmark that I did a long time ago when I was optimizing a game. I cleaned it up a little and rerun some of the basic distances methods to give you a head start:

Remember the never test timing using the DEBUG player, always use the Release version (the debug player's execution times can *vary* by function/feature relative to the release player, 10 times slower in some cases)...

Air/Flash v19 - Release player:

- Total Time (ms): 243 (Point.distance)
- Total Time (ms): 82 (PythaDistance)
- Total Time (ms): 72 (PythaDistanceNoSqrt)
- Total Time (ms): 79 (ManhattanTaxiCab)
- Total Time (ms): 106 (ManhattanTaxiCabNoAbs)

  ```
  private var p1:Point = new Point(5, -6);
  private var p2:Point = new Point(-2.5, 3.5);
  private var d1:Number = 0.0;
  private var collisionDistance:Number = 10.0;
  private var collisionDistanceD:Number = collisionDistance * collisionDistance;

  private var t1:int = 0;
  private var t2:int = 0;
  private var t3:int = 0;

  private function pointDistance(x:int):int {
      t1 = getTimer();
      for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
          d1 = Point.distance(p1, p2);
      }
      if (d1 < collisionDistance) {
          trace("Collision");
      }
      t2 = getTimer();
      return t2 - t1;
  }

  private var dx;
  Number;
  private var dy:Number;

  private function PythaDistance(x:int):int {
      t1 = getTimer();
      for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
          dx = p1.x - p2.x;
          dy = p1.y - p2.y;
          d1 = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      }
      if (d1 < collisionDistance) {
          trace("Collision");
      }
      t2 = getTimer();
      return t2 - t1;
  }

  private function PythaDistanceNoSqrt(x:int):int {
      t1 = getTimer();
      for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
          dx = p1.x - p2.x;
          dy = p1.y - p2.y;
          d1 = (dx * dx + dy * dy);
      }
      if ((d1 * d1) < collisionDistanceD) {
          trace("Collision");
      }
      t2 = getTimer();
      d1 = d1 / 2; // show dist. compared to other ways
      return t2 - t1;
  }

  private function ManhattanTaxiCab(x:int):int {
      t1 = getTimer();
      for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
          dx = p1.x - p2.x;
          dy = p1.y - p2.y;
          d1 = Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy);
      }
      if ((d1 * d1) < collisionDistance) {
          trace("Collision");
      }
      t2 = getTimer();
      return t2 - t1;
  }

  private function ManhattanTaxiCabNoAbs(x:int):int {
      t1 = getTimer();
      for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
          dx = p1.x - p2.x;
          if (dx < 0) dx *= -1;
          dy = p1.y - p2.y;
          if (dy < 0) dy *= -1;
          d1 = dx + dy;
      }
      if ((d1 * d1) < collisionDistance) {
          trace("Collision");
      }
      t2 = getTimer();
      return t2 - t1;
  }
  ```

There are many way to calculate the distance between 2D points and a lot can depend upon how accurate you need the distance/collision to be. Depending upon your framerate, size of objects, size of screen, speed/motion of the sprites, etc... at lot of number fudging can take place without the user noticing (i.e. using integer math vs. floating point can make a huge difference).

Comment: I updated the wording for you: "(the debug player's execution times can *vary* by function/feature relative to the release player, 10 times slower in some cases)" The execution diff between release/debug players are not relative across all function/features.

Comment: Try quake sqrt function. Its 8 times faster than usual.

Comment: I've been googling a bit about it, and it seems is not possible/efficient in AS3.